# Include custom markers at different locations in the plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, annotations, spyder, markers

I am faced with an issue regarding placing custom markers at different locations in the graph. The x and y coordinates of the location of the marker is known. While this seems to be a fairly simple thing to go, I have spent too much time to get this done correctly. I request the Stack Overflow community to please help me. Below is a handwritten plot which shows the type of marker that I want to include in the graph.

[image]

I have included a simple working example of the python plot that generates the plot. Note that I should be able to give the x and y co-ordinates for marker location and also the marker should have a straight dotted line passing along it as shown in the above image. The marker is a **filled circle** whose size should be modified by me.

```
            import numpy as np
            from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
            from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
            #######################################################################
            data5= np.loadtxt('test1.txt',skiprows=1,unpack = True).T
            t3 = data5[:,2]
            C3 = data5[:,3]
            ####################################################################### 
            ######################################################################################################################
            plt.plot(t3,C3,'k',linestyle='solid',linewidth=1.0)
            plt.hold(True)
            plt.tick_params(axis='both',labelsize=9)
            plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
            plt.axhline(y=0.10,xmin=0,xmax=np.argmax(t3),linestyle='dotted',linewidth=0.5,color='black')
            plt.ylabel(r'$t$')
            ######################################################################################################################
            arrow_tip = 1.45,0.28
            text_pos = (1.6,0.25)
            label1=(r'$H=5.0$')
            plt.annotate(label1,xy=arrow_tip,xytext=text_pos,arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",facecolor='black'),fontsize=9.5)   
            plt.text(1.10,0.105,r'Mixing Limit',fontsize=9.5)
            ######################################################################################################################
            plt.xlim(0,t3.max())
            plt.ylim(0,0.35)
            plt.savefig('test.eps',format='eps')
            plt.clf()
            plt.close()
            ######################################################################################################################
```

The result file required for the python code to run is provided at this link [Result File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0jjssdr7jrh8p4/test1.txt?dl=0) .

Thank you very much.

Comment: The marker and the dotted line can be added by two extra plot commands like, for instance,  `plt.plot(t3[100],C3[100],'ok', markersize=10)` and `plt.plot([t3[100], t3[100]] , [C3[100]-0.05, C3[100]+0.05]  ,'--k')`.

Comment: @JanKuiken Thank you very much. Your solution worked. Can you please let me know what does 'ok' represent in the above command?

Comment: The 'o' represents a circle marker and the 'k' represents the color black, see for instance the [online documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).